# MySQL1054 - Unknown column in 'Field List'

Tags: mysql, group-concat

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  Prospect_Id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(Current_Status ORDER BY id) AS myview, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(myview) AS myview1 
FROM prospectdata1 
GROUP BY Prospect_Id 
HAVING myview REGEXP 'PHONE_FOLLOW_UP.*DUPLICATE'
```

i want to show myview data in second group concat..

Comment: Please show corresponding `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery because the column alias is not visible at this point to different columns being selected. I'm assuming that you need a second level of aggregation and that `Prospect_Id` uniquely identifies a row, since you are not grouping by `id`.

Using subquery:

```
SELECT
  id, Prospect_Id, myview, GROUP_CONCAT(myview) AS myview1
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, Prospect_Id, GROUP_CONCAT(Current_Status ORDER BY id) AS myview,
  FROM prospectdata1 
  GROUP BY Prospect_Id 
  HAVING myview REGEXP 'PHONE_FOLLOW_UP.*DUPLICATE'
) t
GROUP BY Prospect_Id
```